# nginx: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, firewall

I wanted to use nginx as a reverse proxy but I somehow can't get it to work.
My config for testing purposes looks as follows:

```
 events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    server {
        listen       81;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name myname.eu;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

If I go to localhost:80 it forwards to the nginx welcome page as expected. If I go to localhost:81 it forwards to some service I have running there. But if I go to myname.eu I will get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The problem is I don't seem to find the reason the connection is blocked. I enabled firewall logging in windows but it does not show up as blocked.

Further if I'm running a website over IIS on port 80 under myname.eu I am able to connect, so the firewall of the router is connfigured correctly.

Any ideas where the block can occur?

Comment: Which server's IP address is assigned to `myname.eu` in DNS? Does the server itself have a global address, or is it behind a NAT?

Comment: It's ipv6 AAAA record.

You actually gave me an idea that my nginx might fail with ipv6 addresses. I found an comment [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/638367/do-you-need-separate-ipv4-and-ipv6-listen-directives-in-nginx) where someone had a problem with nginx and ipv6 I will probably later try the solution and report back if anything changed.

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware that nginx needs a seperate mapping for ipv6. I.e. additionally/instead of

```
listen       80;
```

you would need

```
listen      [::]:80;
```

to not have requests refused.